# How to change title's background color in CupertinoActionSheet flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino, actionsheet

i am using CupertinoActionSheet for bottomsheet. But i have problem with title's background color, i need title's background to be white. I searched but couldn't find a solution for this.
Can you help? is there a way?

[image: "My actionsheet"]

This is my action sheet but i want like this;

[image: ActionSheet which i want]

My DSActionSheet code:
`

```
return CupertinoActionSheet(
      title: Text(
        widget.title ?? "",
      ),
      message: widget.description != null ? Text(
        widget.description!,
      ) : null,
      actions: widget.actionWidgets,
      cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }, 
        child: Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate('cancel')!,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),
        )
      ),
    );`
```

I tried wrap title with container and i gived white color to container, but this isnt work.
Displayed like this:
[image]

I tried giving background color to showModalBottomSheet but then the cancel button doesn't stay separate, it didn't work either.

Comment: As per Flutter doc, there is not much customization option available for the `CupertinoActionSheet`. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoActionSheet-class.html

Comment: If nothing helps: You can also copy the Flutter code and create your own widget with the customizations for the background color

Comment: i solved problem like this: i moved title property to 'CupertinoActionSheet'. and i gave title as a actionWidget (CupertinoActionSheetAction) with onPressed=(){}. 
and it worked ! ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I gave title as an actionwidget and wrap with container and color is white:

```
DSActionSheet(
  actionWidgets: <Widget> [
    Container(
      height: 51,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
        child: Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate("update_profile_photo")!,
          style: ThemeConstants().getActionSheetTitleTextStyle(context)
        ),
        onPressed: (){},
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
        onPressed: () {
          updateProfilePhoto(fromCamera: true);
        }, 
        child: Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate("select_from_camera")!,
        )
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
        onPressed: () {
          updateProfilePhoto(fromCamera: false);
        }, 
        child: Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate("select_from_gallery")!,
        )
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
        isDestructiveAction: true,
        onPressed: () {
          deleteProfilePhoto();
        }, 
        child: Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate("delete_profile_photo")!,
        )
      ),
    ),
  ]
)
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: That is one way to do it.